# Disable responsive Omega

Tags: theming

I am on Omega 4. How do I disable responsive web design for my sub-theme? i.e. fixed grid yet I can still use singularity or other goodies in Omega.

I was from Omega 3.

I would like to quickly get the website up without spending too much time tweaking for RWD.

Comment: If you're just trying to get rid of the fluid layout, you'll just have to set a width on `.l-page`. If it's something else you would have to be more specific

Comment: @Patrick Ryan, I think I got it.

Comment: Thank you. I set .l-page width in 95% in the wrapper. I should have set in fixed pixel. Otherwise, the page will still be fluid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a custom layout (https://drupal.org/node/1936980)
2. Comment (or remove) the "breakpoint" in the scss (or sass).